# Can't compile tmux with iTerm support

Tags: macos, tmux, homebrew, iterm2

I'm trying to [compile the tmux that has iTerm2 support](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/downloads/detail?name=tmux-for-iTerm2-20120203.tar.gz&can=2&q=).

This is the error I get:

```
configure.ac:105: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_SEARCH_LIBS
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf failed
```

The website says:

> If you get an error like "undefined macro: AC_SEARCH_LIBS", run this:
>   echo $(brew --prefix)/share/aclocal | sudo tee -a /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist

Even though I've ran that command (as root), I still have the same results. This is the result of that command:

```
/usr/local/share/aclocal
```

I think the permissions of /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist shouldn't be a problem:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/share/aclocal
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B May  6 20:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  69 root  wheel   2.3K Mar 12 03:18 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    69B May  6 20:54 dirlist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   7.7K Mar  3 20:57 libxml.m4
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   7.9K Mar  3 20:57 libxslt.m4
```

`aclocal`, `automake` and `autoconf` are all in `/usr/local/bin/`, and I've tried installing them through `homebrew` and I also tried compiling and installing them myself. I always have the same results.

Halp?

Comment: What's the content of the `/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist` file?

Comment: /usr/local/share/aclocal, /usr/share/aclocal, /usr/local/share/aclocal. replace ", " with newlines.

Answer (score 4):

I got this after upgrading OS X. It was fixed with: `brew reinstall pkg-config`

Comment: This is the correct solution. Autoconf’s error message is misleading; the problem is not the use of `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, but that of `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` immediately afterwards. This macro is provided by pkgconfig.

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this issue on a mac using **macports** rather than homebrew the suggestion to run:

```
 echo $(brew --prefix)/share/aclocal | sudo tee -a /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist
```

Has the following equivalent:

Ensure that */usr/share/aclocal/dirlist* contains the line */opt/local/share/aclocal* (this is where macports puts macros):

```
echo "/opt/local/share/aclocal" | sudo tee -a /usr/share/aclocal/dirlist
```

Comment: I don’t know if this was ever necessary with MacPorts’ automake, but it definitely isn’t necessary now. `/opt/local/share/aclocal` is in aclocal’s default system includes list.